# If WebSocket Is Used For Our HTML5 App. Should it be used for Server to Server Communication?

Tags: .net, html, websocket, network-programming, tcp

I need to design a solution for an existing system that requires secure two-way communication to be used between multiple applications and services. The current environment is as follows:

1. A HTML5 Kiosk application requires two-way communication to send data and receive data from server. Long-poll and short-poll or REST is not an option because of the requirements. There will be dozens of these Kiosks for users to interact with.
2. There are thousands of locations that have local servers and interact with third-party hardware and software solutions.  Each location will have a local server that has an existing TCP/IP server application that must interact with the third party hardware and software. The client requires that the Kiosk connect to local service due to bandwidth and this third party system.

I am tasked to design an application and network protocol that will:

- Allow secure two-way communication between HTML5 Kiosks with simple data and more complex data such as streaming video and audio.
- Allow secure two-way communication between existing local TCP/IP server application
- Allow secure two-way communication to our central portal system over the internet.

[Here is a link to the design.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLZ8J.png)

This is a Microsoft environment and client prefers to use C# and .NET for server applications. Central system can have a web server (IIS and ASP.NET MVC) but the local servers cannot due hardware and security. All local communication is in a closed network.

My question is:

1. Is there a better solution for two way communication between HTML5 and local server other than Websockets?
2. What network protocol would be best suited for the central network service? This is circled in red in the diagram. These are the protocols we are considering:

   - WebSocket:  Some developers have argued that if Websockets is used for the HTML5 client, then it can be used for two way communication between local and central services. This is purely from development effort and maintenance consideration but I'm not convinced to use it between local and central C# applications. HTTPS and ability to use web ports to avoid opening sockets is another advantage.
   - TCP/IP: Same argument as above. The engineers already have some TCP/IP experience and can reuse code from other applications to speed up development.
   - WCF Duplex: This makes sense to me but adds layer of complexity that is a hard sell to the engineers and management. Configuration of WCF, troubleshooting is also a barrier because the deployment must be fast at each location. This used to be an issue a few years ago but I believe WCF configuration has gotten easier. The network service applications will do a lot more than networking so WCF would be on top of existing components.
   - Any other protocol or technology that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

WebSockets looks like ok for client-server communication.

Pay attention if client's web browser doesn't support web sockets natively a long-polling may be chosen (by your framework) as a fallback.
So I would say your system should be ready for some level of load in any case.

For server-server communication there is a trend to use REST or messaging (RabbitMq, Kafka, etc)